# What is translations in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel just working on larapay template i want to know about translations.

**Below is my code to create one label and input on form:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('hsnsac',trans('HSN/SAC').' '.trans('code'),[])!!}
  {!! Form::input('number','hsnsac',isset($item) ? $item->hsnsac : '',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('HSN/SAC').' '.trans('messages.code')])!!}
</div>
```

**Below is default code for display elements:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('code',trans('messages.item').' '.trans('messages.code'),[])!!}
 {!! Form::input('text','code',isset($item) ? $item->code : '',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>trans('messages.item').' '.trans('messages.code')])!!}
</div>
```

i cant understand what is `trans(messages)` in code.
and if i used my own code like `trans(messages.hsnsac)` it will display this **messages.hsnsac** on form.

Comment: You want to read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trans` is a shortcut helper to the `lang` directory in your `resources` directory.

If your `lang` is set to `en` it will attempt to derive from this. Because the notation is dot based, the first word will be the file name, the second will be the key, like this:

```
resources
|
| ---- lang
      |
      | ---- en
            |
            | ---- messages.php
```

Now you need to return an array fro this file.

```
return [
    'hsnsac' => 'This text will appear now';
];
```

Finally, if you call `trans('messages.hsnsac')` it will return `This text will appear now`.

Mind you, this is only for `en`. If you are using another language, make sure the file exists in a directory for that `lang` under `resources/lang` as well.

Comment: alternative: `__('file.key')` I don't know if there should be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [define these translation strings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#defining-translation-strings).

Create the file `resources/lang/{language}/messages.php` and add your translations here.